# タイトル欄でエンターを押したときにサブミットされるのを避けたい

Tags: 機能の要求, 対応予定

タイトル欄でエンターを押すとフォームがサブミットされます。

日本語は漢字変換でエンターを多用するので間違ってサブミットする人も多いと思います。

本文がバリデーションエラーになるのでそのまま投稿されるケースは少ないと思いますが、ちょっとびっくりするので、エンター押下時のサブミットは無効にした方がいいと思いました。